# Error connecting to Icecast

Tags: icecast

I have setup Icecast server on Ubuntu 14.04. I am using ezstream source client to send to the Icecast server. Everything seems to work for a while. After I load many streams, Icecast seems to hang and does not accept the new request.

Log for Icecast:

```
[2014-08-20  05:07:24] EROR connection/_handle_connection Wrong request type from client
[2014-08-20  05:07:24] INFO source/source_main listener count on /streaming/76cafede98c3aa484821fe707f3a919f now 0
```

Occasionally, log reports this error as well:

```
 WARN source/get_next_buffer Disconnecting source due to socket timeout
```

Comment: Do a packet capture so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Which Icecast version are you using? And how many streams (mountpoints) are you trying to stream? Additionally it would help if you show your ezstream and Icecast config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are overloading your network?

```
WARN source/get_next_buffer Disconnecting source due to socket timeout
```

The above error usually happens when the source client fails to send data fast enough to the Icecast server.